# Bind Request to Type in a Razor Layout ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I know that the `ASP.NET MVC` framework can bind an incoming request to an instance of a given `Type` at the `controller` level.

However, I want to be able to bind to a Known Type instance somewhere in my Razor Layout from the current Request context.

Is this possible ??

Comment: Please make it clear with relavant code samples

Comment: Is this type something other than the view's model?

Comment: I found the answer to what I was looking for here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788948/is-model-binding-possible-without-mvc